# WinHttpSendRequest in async mode doesn't send POST data

Tags: c++, post, asynchronous, winhttp

I'm having an issue sending POST data via WinHttpSendRequest in asynchronous mode.

In synchronous mode:

```
WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(request_handles.at(handler_index), L"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded", -1L, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
int rc = WinHttpSendRequest(request_handles.at(handler_index), WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, (LPVOID)postData.c_str(), dataLen, dataLen, 0);
```

Works like a charm. My server gets the postData as I'd expect it.

In asynchronous mode:

```
WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK cb = WinHttpSetStatusCallback(request_handles.at(handler_index), httpReadCallback, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE | WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR |
    WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REDIRECT | WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SECURE_FAILURE | WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_INTERMEDIATE_RESPONSE |
    WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_CLOSING_CONNECTION | WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_CONNECTION_CLOSED, NULL);
WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(request_handles.at(handler_index), L"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded", -1L, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
 int rc = WinHttpSendRequest(request_handles.at(handler_index), WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, (LPVOID)postData.c_str(), dataLen, dataLen, 0);
```

The server receives a POST request, but without a data body. What gives?

Comment: Does `postData` get destroyed soon after that call, by any chance? You must preserve the buffer until `WinHttpReceiveResponse` call.